# EAN and UPC codes on Amazon

Tags: legal, software

I want to add my first software product as an independent programmer to my Amazon store. However, they are asking me for an EAN or UPC code. I can buy one for about 10 pounds, but will one be sufficient for all my stock of 100 CDs (of the same product)? Or do I have to purchase 100 separate EAN codes?

Comment: What does this question have to do with freelancing? This is a programming question or logistics question but not a freelancing question.

Comment: Frankly there was nowhere else I could post this, even if it's not 100% relevant, it's MOST relevant on this forum

Comment: @Pickle Although I don't see how this could be a "freelance" question, I'm going to leave it open, and invite you to post on [meta], or come into [chat]. We are still in beta, and determining what's on topic or not is something we love testing

Comment: @JakeGould, CanadianLuke, Pickle, I went ahead and opened a [meta discussion for this post](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/202/what-constitutes-a-freelancing-problem-on-freelancing-se).

Comment: @Pickle Is there any reason you are not posing the question directly to Amazon’s support team? This seems like a painfully simple, “I want to use your service, what does your service provide?” question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because pre-sales questions are best answered by the service provider and because the answer may change from time to time as service terms and conditions can be varied by the service provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one code for every distinct product. So for 100 identical products probably one code will be enough. But if you want to add an expansion pack or version 2.0 or anything else than the original, you will need new codes. Or you just keep selling them under the old code, but then the user can't distinguish them on the shops.

Also there has been rumours of free codes from amazon, according to amazon they are not true.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This answers my question perfectly.